# Shiny Error, no output

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have to create a dashboard, it will take csv file as a input, which is given by user, then it will select variable from entity column(facility & Uen) after selecting one variable we should get that variable data in uen column from user data file, then after selecting 1 uen data we will get all variables data for that uen

```
a = read.csv("input_missing.csv")
ui <- fluidPage ( 
tabsetPanel (
tabPanel("Input Data", fluid = TRUE,

         titlePanel(title=div( "Risk Rating Model", align = "center")),

         wellPanel(
           fluidRow(width = 2,column(width =  3, fileInput(  "file1", "Import the data file", accept = c(".csv"))),
                    column(width =  2, selectInput(  "file2", "Entity Details", c(" ", "Facility Id", "UEN "), selected=" ")),
                    column(width =  2, selectInput('FacilityId', 'Facility Id', a$CCDM_FacilityId)),
                    column(width =  2, selectInput('UEN', 'UEN Id', list(),, multiple = TRUE))
           ),

           fluidRow(
             DT::dataTableOutput("contents")


           )

         ))))

server <-function(input, output,session) { 

output$contents <- renderTable({

inFile <- input$file1

if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
 })




 observe({
updateSelectizeInput(session, "UEN", choices = a$input$file2)  
       })


 # Filter data based on selections
  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({

if (input$FacilityId != "All") {
  a <- a[a$CCDM_FacilityId == input$FacilityId,]
}
if (input$UEN != "All") {
  a <- a[a$UEN1 == input$UEN,]
}


a
 }))

 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of inconsistencies with this shiny that will cause you problems (`list(),,`, undefined `a`, multiple `output$contents`, etc.).  I recommend you start with a working example and then build from there.  Take a look at the working example here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/fileInput.html

Comment: I have defined a and i had seen this web page before, but not able to solve this,can u help?

Answer (score 0):

try with changing the first renderTable statement to a reactive statement like this

```
dta_table <- eventReactive(input$file1,{  
  inFile <- input$file1
  read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
 })
```

and then add `a <- dta_table()` to the second call of renderTable

```
output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
  a <- dta_table()
  if (input$FacilityId != "All") {
    a <- a[a$CCDM_FacilityId == input$FacilityId,]
  }
  if (input$UEN != "All") {
    a <- a[a$UEN1 == input$UEN,]
  }
  a
}))
```

Hope this helps!!